# ORA-01841 , (full) year must be between

Tags: oracle, epoch

I want to convert the epoch date from table into timestamp.

But it results in an error when I run it in Oracle.

But the year showing into "Rabu, 22 April 2465 pukul 15.35.06.289 GMT+07:00" when i run from this link "https://www.epochconverter.com/'

15630394456289509085900
this the epoch time from table

```
select to_char(
           cast(
               to_date('01/01/1970 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+15630394456289509085900/86400 
           as timestamp with local time zone)
         ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
from dual
```

Comment: Obviously, your formula is interpreting the "epoch time" as seconds, when in fact that number looks like picoseconds (1 / 10 ^ 12 seconds). To get the correct time, you must divide by 86400000000000000  -  that is, add 12 more zeros to the denominator. Note that Oracle timestamp only supports nanoseconds (1 / 10 ^ 9 seconds), so you **will** lose precision.

Comment: Thank you btw, so i cannot change the epoch date because it to long ?

Comment: You're trying to add 5e14 years to 1970, and that's wayyyyyyyy beyond what Oracle supports as years in a date. Follow comment by @mathguy and you get the result

Comment: For sure 15630394456289509085900  is not a Unix timestamp. My first idea was, it could be LDAP timestamp which is `100 nanoseconds since 1601-01-01 00:00:00 UTC` - however this would result to 49.5 million years which is also very unlikely.

Comment: `DATE` data type does not contain any time zone information. When you run `CAST(<DATE> as timestamp with local time zone)` then Oracle implies `SESSIONTIMEZONE`. Verify that this is set to `UTC`

Answer (score 1):

Epoch times are in the UTC time zone. Just use a `TIMESTAMP` literal and add the correct amount of seconds:

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
         + NUMTODSINTERVAL(15630394456289509085900 / 86400e12, 'DAY') AS epoch_time_12,
       TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
         + NUMTODSINTERVAL(15630394456289509085900 / 86400e13, 'DAY') AS epoch_time_13
FROM   DUAL
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> EPOCH_TIME_12                     | EPOCH_TIME_13                    
> :-------------------------------- | :--------------------------------
> 2465-04-22 08:14:16.289509086 UTC | 2019-07-13 17:37:25.628950909 UTC
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bc1832045470c745b1761c7e9035ab91)*